# Can 'bad questions' still be considered helpful for future research?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, downvotes

Today I've come over [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386938/how-to-run-main-class-in-c) (as found at 1st edit stage):

[image]

My first reaction was to down and close vote the question, and leaving some comments along (which I'm afraid just tracked a number of other users to down/close vote as well).

Now, I'm back home sweet and cosy, I have changed my mind considering this could be a **"valid"** question, but at least helpful for future research of apprentices, who will need to switch from other languages to c++, and composed an IMHO suitable [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386938/how-to-run-main-class-in-c/26388360#26388360) for this.

I've been retracting my down- & close-votes, and left a comment why.

**My questions are:**

1. Even if a question has downvotes applied (e.g. because of poorly met policies), could it be considered useful for future research (and thus shouldn't necessarily be closed/deleted)?
2. How should I improve that question by editing, to better fit the actual policies?

Comment: Sure, any real question could potentially be helpful to someone else, at least theoretically even if the chances of that happening are very slim. What's the point of this question?

Comment: I see the question linked as being valid, if it isn't a duplicate. It certainly isn't unclear or too broad, it's specific. I would agree with downvotes though, as a little bit of research would have solved this question without having to ask.

Comment: @KevinB I'm just stating, that asking for such, could be a **very common** misconception for [tag:c#]/[tag:java] developers, and though of the bad question, there are valid answers to clarify for [tag:c++] to help future researchers.

Comment: @KevinB _"I see the question linked as being valid, if it isn't a duplicate."_ I'm a bit stuck, banging it into a better shape now. Smells like a _canonical_ (regarding that mentioned misconceptions) for me.

Comment: I'm still hoping for some edit suggestions, how the original question could be improved.